# Sending an IForm from a LUIS intent

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, formflow

I currently have a chatbot running in visual studio using Microsoft's bot framework in the language c#.
I integrated LUIS into the bot and I'm wondering how can I make it so that a FormFlow similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow) example appears on a specific intent.

So far this is the code for my Form:

```
internal static IDialog<InfoGroup> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(InfoGroup.BuildForm));
    }
public enum GroupOptions
{
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
};
[Serializable]
public class InfoGroup
{
    public GroupOptions? groupId;

    public static IForm<InfoGroup> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<InfoGroup>()
                .Message("Please select an option")
                .Build();
    }
};
```

And I'm trying to send it form my LUIS intent method like so:

```
[LuisIntent("SpecificGroup")]
    public async Task SpecificGroupIntent(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync(FormDialog.FromForm(InfoGroup.BuildForm));
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        return;
    }
```

This is obviously not the correct way to call the form, how can I make it so that a form appears as a response called directly from my SpecificGroupIntent() method?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
After the form is filled I want to use the option that the user selected to display text accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the formflow builder from a luis intent method like calling a dialog from a parent dialog using the context.Call() method. You will also need to specify a method that will be executed once the form is filled.

Eg:
Calling the formbuilder by creating a FormDialog of InfoGroup(Your form) type and specifying method to be executed after it.

```
InfoGroup form = new InfoGroup();    
FormDialog<InfoGroup> InfoGroupform = new FormDialog<InfoGroup>(form, InfoGroup.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
context.Call(InfoGroupform, InfoGroupFormSubmitted);
```

InfoGroupFormSubmitted is the method that will be called once your form is filled. You need this because if you are using context.Call() method you need to specify a resumeAfter method for it. In this InfoGroupFormSubmitted method you can just give a confirmation if the form was correctly filled or if the user quit you can just catch the exception and show where the user quit.

```
public static async Task InfoGroupFormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<InfoGroup> result)
{
        try
        {
             var query = await result;
             context.PostAsync("Your choice has been recorded.");
        } 
        catch (FormCanceledException<InfoGroup> e)
        {
              string reply;
              if (e.InnerException == null)
              {
                    reply = $"You quit on {e.Last}--maybe you can finish next time!";
              }
              else
              {
                    reply = $"Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
              }
              context.Done(true);
              await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very complete answer, the only problem is that after trying this I get this error when entering my LUIS intent, any suggestions?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Woops my bad I had an context.Wait(MessageReceived); after my form call which is redundant and was causing the error, thanks for your answer it works perfectly!!!

Comment: Happy to help :D